Undefined instruction MRS on bare metal
I want to run simple test code in C on the Renesas Synergy R7FS5D97E evaluation board (Cortex M4). I made a sample project + SDK and toolchain projects using official materials, successfully built and flashed it using Ozone debugger.
However, when I run it, an exception is raised on startup: HardFault with undefined instruction flag when executing MRS R1, PRIMASK in function R_BSP_RegisterProtectEnable.
It'd be understandable if it happened the first time this instruction was executed, but it's not - in fact, it's about 15th time this instruction (in this exact function and even the same value of PRIMASK register) is executed during the program's run, so it can't be simply unsupported on this hardware.
I managed to trace where the error happens: the call of R_BSP_RegisterProtectEnable/HW_CGC_HardwareLock right after SystemInit (system_S5D9.c:171) -> bsp_clock_init (bsp_clocks.c:150) -> R_CGC_SystemClockSet (r_cgc.c:707) -> r_cgc_system_dividers_set (r_cgc.c:2637), so I'm wondering if it could be some kind of clock configuration problem? In Ozone, I'm simply using default settings offered for this board.
Alternatively, I could've made a mistake in preparing this SDK and toolchain - I had to manually cobble together a pure Conan+CMake project from Renesas configuration files and perhaps I missed something. Still, it doesn't make sense for this specific instruction to fail. It's simply copying a special register value to a general register.
I've run the same kind of thing on a different Renesas Synergy board years ago (different SDK and toolchain files), and had my fair share of trouble there, but never this - and it worked in the end.
Attached system state before the error and the HardFault details from Ozone since I can't copy it as text.
SDK project, toolchain project; I don't think the sample project matters as the error happens during startup, but I can upload it if needed.
UPD: The error happens when setting ICLK divider and clock source in this branch. Clock source is set first in function r_cgc_clock_source_set, that calls R_BSP_RegisterProtectDisable, performs a store and calls R_BSP_RegisterProtectEnable. The first instruction in R_BSP_RegisterProtectEnable is MRS R1, PRIMASK, which executes successfully here. Assembly (inlined function):
LDR.W          R8, [R7, #28]
BL             R_BSP_RegisterProtectDisable
LDRB.W         R3, [R8, #38]
BFI            R3, R6, #0, #3
MOV            R0, R5
STRB.W         R3, [R8, #38]
BL             R_BSP_RegisterProtectEnable

Then the function r_cgc_system_dividers_set is called (source link). Assembly (this time non-inline):
LDR            R0, [R7, #28]
MOV            R1, R4
BL             r_cgc_system_dividers_set
~~~
PUSH           {R4-R6, LR}
LDRB           R2, [R1]
LDRB           R3, [R1, #1]
LDRB           R6, [R1, #2]
LDRB           R5, [R1, #3]
MOVS           R4, #0
AND            R3, R3, #7
BFI            R4, R2, #12, #3
LDR            R2, =gp_cgc_feature           ; [PC, #64] [0x00001CC0] =0x1FFE0214 
BFI            R4, R3, #8, #3
LDR            R2, [R2]
BFI            R4, R6, #4, #3
LDRB           R6, [R1, #4]
LDRB.W         R2, [R2, #42]
BFI            R4, R5, #0, #3
LDRB           R5, [R1, #5]
LDRB           R1, [R1, #6]
BFI            R4, R6, #16, #3
BFI            R4, R5, #28, #3
BFI            R4, R1, #24, #3
MOV            R5, R0
LSLS           R2, R2, #29
IT             MI
BFIMI          R4, R3, #16, #3
MOVS           R0, #0
BL             R_BSP_RegisterProtectDisable
STR            R4, [R5, #32]
MOVS           R0, #0
POP.W          {R4-R6, LR}
B.W            R_BSP_RegisterProtectEnable

This time, the first instruction MRS R1, PRIMASK in R_BSP_RegisterProtectEnable throws the undefined instruction error instead.
It's really starting to stink of bad clock configuration, but this code is downloaded from Renesas website for this exact device so I don't dare tinker with it unless I know exactly what to do. Hence my question.
UPD2: Internal clock divider in bsp_clock_cfg.h didn't match the manufacturer's files! Either I made a typo or reused a file from a different project, and didn't notice a problem because /1 seems like an ok internal clock divider, but changing it to /2 fixed this error. Perhaps it was causing instruction fetch/prefetch from flash to only finish after attempted decode...
Note that this file is normally auto-generated by Renesas software from XML configs (which include default values). I found those XMLs but needed to manually create headers with all required macros from them.
Thanks to everyone for the brainstorm session!

It could be that the instruction memory is modified (buffer overflow?) an the actual MRS instruction is overwritten with junk. You should examine this memory and make sure the instruction is still there. I am assuming your arch has this instruction defined, as I am lazy to look up in the specs...

Try stripping everything out a little at a time until you have a minimal reproducible example.

@EugeneSh. The instruction resides in code flash (the board's datasheet mentions a flash cache but I don't know if it could affect things or if I could check that at all) according to linker script and addresses shown in debugger, so any attempt to overwrite that should result in an earlier error. As far as I can see, it doesn't seem overwritten, the debugger's memory view shows the same bytes EF F3 10 81 during execution. Nonetheless, it's a good guess and I'll keep an eye on it.

@TomV Can't really do that with system code. At most I can prune seemingly unused units, but if anything, there could be something missing that's causing the error instead. System code should be used in full, the sample project was already MRE but it's not executed as the error happens in system init.

From your ozone link/image, is the program counter really 0xFFFFFFFE? Or, is that just the reset value (and the actual faulting instruction address is lost)?

@CraigEstey After the error, it's lost. Same for stack trace, so I had to manually find the faulting instruction and the error happens when I single-step over it. From the screenshot before the error, you can see the correct address 0x11124 in PC.

Just a guess ... From the before trace, has the MRS R1,PRIMASK been executed (or the one that will be executed on the next single step)? Is that the faulting instruction or the last valid one before the fault? It seems strange to me that reading a control register generates a fault. I'd expect that writing (i.e. MSR) could cause a fault. Has MRS Rx,PRIMASK (or whatever inst that faults) been executed successfully(!) before? If so, where and what instructions follow that up to the faulting one? (i.e. what inst sequence changed state so the faulting inst worked and then not worked).

In other words, find the last valid execution of the offending instruction. Then, step through all subsequent instructions up to the fault. What instructions could change state to cause the fault?

@CraigEstey It's the faulting instruction and it's also strange to me as it's executed successfully about 15 times before that. Exactly that instruction/address. Right before that, we perform a system register STR link, successfully branch into R_BSP_RegisterProtectEnable and try to execute the starting macros defined in link. The failing instruction is the call of __get_PRIMASK().

@Xellos After some thought ... A guess ... If/when you pinpoint the exact inst that faults (e.g. mrs r1,primask). Determine a "safe point" where the inst works as normal. Change build to generate .s files via -S. Inject a "harmless" version of mrs after each inst. Then build the .o from the .s. Singlestep these. The inst before the mrs that (now) faults will be the inst that changes the state to ruin mrs You could limit the injections to only after "interesting" insts that mess with config regs

@Xellos What I mean is: Suppose we have some [flattened] sequence of instructions: mrs (last good) i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, ..., i99, mrs (fault). We only know that somewhere in i1-i99 something changes that borks the mrs--but what??? If we change to: mrs, i1, mrs, i2, mrs, i3, mrs, i4, mrs, i5, mrs, ... i99, mrs, now we should see an immediate fault after the final instruction that misconfigures things (e.g. i37). Now we know that i37 (or some sequence up to it) causes the problem. That is, we eliminated i38-i99 as an issue. Gets us closer.

@Xellos The injecting of instructions into a .s file isn't as crazy as it sounds. It can be automated with a script. See my answer: Keep target address of load in register until instruction is retired

One of the usual suspects: does this part come with flash wait states or not, for the given clock frequency?

https://www.google.com/search?q=Cortex-m+imprecise+HardFault

@artless-noise-bye-due2AI: the crash dump shows that the Imprecise flag is unset. Would undefined instruction ever be an imprecise fault anyway?

@Lundin Datasheet says zero wait states in general.

I did a simple test of "comment out offending call and retry", lo and behold, same error on an ADD instruction a few cycles later. Seems it's not this specific instruction but something getting broken in clock setting. Just in case, I'm going to doublecheck if I didn't copy something incorrectly from Renesas' zips.

@Xellos If there's external quartz you could measure the clock easily enough and see if the oscillator goes on at all. With the classic HC49 SMD crystals there's often soldering problems.

Internal clock divider needed to be set to CGC_SYS_CLOCK_DIV_2 (default from manufacturer's XML configs) instead of CGC_SYS_CLOCK_DIV_1. I made some mistake when creating the SDK.
